# Angular UI-Router Abstract Parent state resolve data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angular-ui-router

I have the following `ui-router` state configuration:

```
angular
.module('my_app', ['ui.router'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    .state('main', {
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            "header": {
                templateUrl: "app/views/shared/header.html",
                controller: "MainController",
                controllerAs: "main"
            },
            "content": {
                template: "<ui-view />"
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            mobile: mobileCheck
        }
    })
    .state('main.home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController',
        controllerAs: 'home',
    })
    .state('main.earn', {
        url: '/earn',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/templates/earn.html',
        controller: "EarnController",
        controllerAs: 'earn',
    })
    .state('main.vision', {
        url: '/vision',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/templates/vision.html',
        controller: "VisionController",
        controllerAs: "vision"
    })
    .state('main.contact', {
        url: '/contact',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/templates/contact.html',
        controller: "ContactController",
        controllerAs: "contact"
    })
});
```

Here, I have an abstract parent state, `main`, and each child state (`main.home`, `main.earn`, etc) is a different page in the application.
The abstract state exists to use a common template, the header, above all the page templates:

```
views: {
    "header": {
        templateUrl: "app/views/shared/header.html",
        controller: "MainController",
            controllerAs: "main"
        },
        "content": {
            template: "<ui-view />"
        }
    }
```

where the corresponding html looks like:

```
<body ng-controller="MainController as main" ng-cloak>
    <div ui-view='header'></div>
    <div ui-view='content'></div>

    <script src="app/app.js"></script>

    <!-- AngularJS Controllers -->
    <script src="app/controllers/mainController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/homeController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/earnController.js"></script>
</body>
```

the `header` named view is where the header gets injected and the `content` view holds each of the page templates.

As you can see, I've defined the main controller on the body of the entire document as well as given controller aliases to specific page templates so I should be able to access both `home` and `main` inside any of the page templates which I was able to confirm works.

What doesn't work however is accessing my resolved data inside the main controller. I can access inside each of the page templates but not the main "parent" controller. Each page controller gets passed the `mobile` dependency that it can then attach to `this` which is used to detect mobile/desktop environments. I would much rather be able to receive the `mobile` dependency inside `MainController` but whenever I try `.controller('MainController', function(mobile)`, I get the standard angular error about incorrect dependency injection.

This leads me to believe that the resolve data is getting resolved down to the child states (and controllers) but not into the parent controller. I think it's because 1) the parent abstract state has no `url` and 2) because the controller for that state is named on the body, not on the state itself.

How can I get the resolved data to resolve into my main controller as a dependency? I've tried naming the controller inside the state config but that had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem not long after posting the question but figured I should post my discoveries/answers anyway.

To recap my goals were:

1. Combine both named and non-named `ui-view` tags
2. Have data resolve into the parent controller and into all child states
3. Access both the parent controller and child controller inside the child controller's html template.

I'll cover how I solved each from 1 to 3, all of which related to the larger question of how to resolve data into an abstract state and it's children.

First, looking at my body tag:

```
<body ng-controller="MainController as main" ng-cloak>
```

Having the parent controller defined on the body tag instead of inside the state provider meant that any resolved data wasn't getting passed to the `MainController` instance being instantiated by the body but was getting passed into the `MainController` instances specified in my config. Either way, the body controller was causing the application to crash because of the dependency injection issue.

So I removed the `ng-controller` from the body tag. Then to have both named views and a regular `<ui-view>` tag that the pages get injected into, you make two named `ui-view`s in your `index.html` file:

```
<div ui-view='header'></div>
<div ui-view='content'></div>
```

and in the state config:

```
.state('main', {
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        "header": {
            templateUrl: "app/views/shared/header.html",
            controller: "MainController",
            controllerAs: "main"
        },
        "content": {
            template: "<ui-view />"
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        mobile: mobileCheck
    }
})
```

where the shared views will load from the specified templateURL and the pages get injected into the `ui-view` inside the named `content` tag.

So here we've solved 1 and 2. We have both named views while being able to inject pages and all the controller instances received the resolved dependencies. But now, even though the header has access to the main controller, any pages inside the `content` tag don't.
And unfortunately, naming the controller in the state like:

```
.state('main', {
    controller: "MainController",
    controllerAs: "main",
    views: { ... }
```

doesn't work either.

The simple trick then is to define the main controller on all the subviews:

```
views: {
    "header": {
        templateUrl: "app/views/shared/header.html",
        controller: "MainController",
        controllerAs: "main"
    },
    "content": {
        template: "<ui-view />",
        controller: "MainController",
        controllerAs: "main"
    }
}
```

Now the shared views have access to the parent controller and the child templates have access to both controllers. Thus, you can define common state on the parent controller, such as if the environment is mobile instead of defining it on each sub-controller.

NOTE:

Because the main controller is defined in two places, the main controller gets instantiated twice. You can solved this by making some kind of service or something and having a shared variable for the parent controller

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make service or `provider` out of your `mobileCheck` so you don't have to resolve it for your states at all? Consider

```
.provider('mobileCheck', function mobileCheck() {
  this.$get = function() {
    return {
      isMobile: function() {
        return true;
      }
    };
  };
})

.controller('MainController', function(mobileCheck) {
  var main = this;
  main.isMobile = mobileCheck.isMobile();
})

.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('main', {
      abstract: true,
      views: { 
        'header': {
          template: '<div>abstract state : main (isMobile {{ main.isMobile  }})</div>',
          controller: 'MainController',
          controllerAs: 'main'
        },
        'content': {
          template: '<ui-view />'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('main.home', {
      url: '/',
      template: '<div>concrete state : home  (isMobile {{ main.isMobile  }})</div>',
      controller: angular.noop
    });
});
```

With HTML template like you have

```
<body ng-controller="MainController as main" ng-cloak>
  <div ui-view="header"></div>
  <div ui-view="content"></div>
  <hr>
  <div>
    <a ui-sref="main.home">main.home</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Would give you something like

[image: img]